# How do I make "download" and "Live Preview" buttons appear when user logged in but only "Live Preview" button when user logged out?

Tags: php, html

My script for demo 3 - I'm trying to use 3 statement conditions to make "download" and "Live Preview" buttons appear when user logged in but only "Live Preview" button when user logged out.

```
            <div class="card-body pb-md-5">
                <h4 class="font-weight-bold mb-3">Demo 3</h4>
                <p>This template is ideal for producers who want to sell their beats using <b>"Airbit"</b> beat player. It's crafted with <img src="icons/fa-heart.png" height="16"> using Bootstrap 4. You can request for changes in color and beat player(e.g, You can use Beatstars or any beat player you are already using).</p>

                    <?php
                        if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
                        echo '<span><a class="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-md" href="#">Download</a></span>';
                    }
                    elseif (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
                        echo '<span><a class="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-md" href="#">Download</a></span>';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<a class="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-md" href="www.jbstrap.tk/demo1">Live Demo</a>';
                    }
                    ?>
            </div>
```

My script for demo 4 - This statement for 2 conditions works pretty well but it's not how I want it because the user can only see the download button when logged in.

```
            <div class="card-body pb-5">
                <h4 class="font-weight-bold mb-3">Demo 4</h4>
                <p>This template is ideal for producers who want to sell their beats using <b>"Airbit"</b> beat player. It's crafted with <img src="icons/fa-heart.png" height="16"> using Bootstrap 4. You can request for changes in color and beat player(e.g, You can use Beatstars or any beat player you are already using).</p>


                    <?php
                        if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
                        echo '<span><a class="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-md" href="#">Download</a></span>';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<a class="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-md" href="www.jbstrap.tk/demo1">Live Demo</a>';
                    }
                    ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: Why do you check whether the userId is stored in the session twice? And what exactly does not work with the given code? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of if/else it will show live preview if the userId isn't set. So you can just add another line to the if true statement.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
    echo '<span><a class="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-md" href="#">Download</a></span>';
    echo '<a class="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-md" href="www.jbstrap.tk/demo1">Live Demo</a>';
}
else {
    echo '<a class="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-md" href="www.jbstrap.tk/demo1">Live Demo</a>';
}
```

All the best, MrBurt

Ps: if you happen to do alot of html code in php then take a look at HEREDOC, you might like it better than above.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the else conditional. It is not needed.

For example:

```html
<div class="card-body pb-5">
  <h4 class="font-weight-bold mb-3">Demo 4</h4>
  <p>This template is ideal for producers who want to sell their beats using <b>"Airbit"</b> beat player. It's crafted with <img src="icons/fa-heart.png" height="16"> using Bootstrap 4. You can request for changes in color and beat player(e.g, You can use Beatstars or any beat player you are already using).</p>
  <?php
      if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) {
          echo '<span><a class="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-md" href="#">Download</a></span>';
      }

      echo '<a class="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-md" href="www.jbstrap.tk/demo1">Live Demo</a>';
  ?>
</div>
```

That way the Live Demo button will always appear, but the Download button will only appear if they are logged in.